# Itunes API Use With JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, itunes, itunes-store

I am using the code below which i found on: http://www.rahulsingla.com/blog/2011/08/itunes-performing-itunes-store-search-in-javascript to pull songs from Itunes based on a keyword, however i only want to pull songs on page-load without having to use the search box, lets say my keyword is "search-keyword", i would like to display songs immidiately on page-load or refresh without using the search box, here is the code below:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>iTunes - Music Search in javascript</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 

        <style type="text/css">
        .songs-search-result {
            border: 1px solid Gray;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
            padding: 5px;
        }

        .songs-search-result  .label{
            display: inline-block;
            width: 200px;
        }
        </style>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function urlEncode(obj) {
                var s = '';
                for (var key in obj) {
                    s += encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(obj[key]) + '&';
                }
                if (s.length > 0) {
                    s = s.substr(0, s.length - 1);
                }

                return (s);
            }

            function performSearch() {
                var params = {
                    term: encodeURIComponent(jQuery('#search-keyword').val()),
                    country: 'US',
                    media: 'music',
                    entity: 'musicTrack',
                    //attribute: 'artistTerm,albumTerm,songTerm,musicTrackTerm',
                    limit: 20,
                    callback: 'handleTunesSearchResults'
                };
                var params = urlEncode(params);

                var url = 'http://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/wa/wsSearch?' + params;
                var html = '<script src="' + url + '"><\/script>';
                jQuery('head').append(html);
            }

            function handleTunesSearchResults(arg) {
                var results = arg.results;
                var html = '';
                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    var item = results[i];
                    var obj = {
                        source: 0,
                        track_id: item.trackId,
                        track_name: item.trackCensoredName,
                        track_url: item.trackViewUrl,
                        artist_name: item.artistName,
                        artist_url: item.artistViewUrl,
                        collection_name: item.collectionCensoredName,
                        collection_url: item.collectionViewUrl,
                        genre: item.primaryGenreName
                    };
                    results[i] = obj;

                    html += '<div class="songs-search-result">';

                    html += '<span class="label">Track:</span>{0}&nbsp;&nbsp;'.replace("{0}", obj.track_name);
                    html += '<a href="{0}" target="_blank">Preview</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;'.replace("{0}", item.previewUrl);
                    html += '<a href="{0}" target="_blank">Full Song</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;'.replace("{0}", obj.track_url);
                    html += '<span class="label">Track Price:</span>{0} {1}<br />'.replace("{0}", item.trackPrice).replace("{1}", item.currency);
                    html += '<span class="label">Artist:</span><a href="{0}" target="_blank">{1}</a><br />'.replace("{0}", obj.artist_url).replace("{1}", obj.artist_name);
                    html += '<span class="label">Collection:</span><a href="{0}" target="_blank">{1}</a><br />'.replace("{0}", obj.collection_url).replace("{1}", obj.collection_name);
                    html += '<span class="label">Collection Price:</span>{0} {1}<br />'.replace("{0}", item.collectionPrice).replace("{1}", item.currency);
                    html += '<span class="label">Primary Genre:</span>{0}<br />'.replace("{0}", obj.genre);

                    html += '</div>';
                }
                jQuery('#itunes-results').html(html);
            }       
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        Please enter a search term below (e.g. Michael):<br />
        <input type="text" id="search-keyword" title="Enter Search Keyword" />
        <br />
        <input type="button" value="Perform iTunes Search" onclick="performSearch();" />

        <div id="itunes-results">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```